# Wrapping an ant-design form component

Tags: javascript, antd

I've been trying to figure out how to wrap an ant-design form component. I have several `Select`s that will have the same options, so I wanted to create a `SelectWrapper` (see snippet below). Unfortunately, antd's form doesn't seem to like this and will error with

> createBaseForm.js:98 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onChange' of undefined

despite me passing through the form props to the `Select`.

```
function ReusableCountrySelect({countries, ...props}) {
  return (
    <Select
      {...props}
    >
      {
        countries.map(c => (
          <Select.Option
            value={c.id}
            key={c.id}
          >{c.name}</Select.Option>
        ))
      }
    </Select>
  );
}
```

Full example (requires babel for the spread)

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
const mountNode = document.getElementById('root');

import {
  Form, Select, Button
} from 'antd';
const FormItem = Form.Item;
const Option = Select.Option;

function ReusableCountrySelect({countries, ...props}) {
  return (
    <Select
      {...props}
    >
      {
        countries.map(c => (
          <Select.Option
            value={c.id}
            key={c.id}
          >{c.name}</Select.Option>
        ))
      }
    </Select>
  );
}

class Demo extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

        <FormItem
          label="Select Country"
          hasFeedback
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('select', {
            rules: [
              { required: true, message: 'Please select your country!' },
            ],
          })(
            <ReusableCountrySelect
              countries={[
                {name: 'china', id: 'china'},
                {name: 'india', id: 'india'},
                {name: 'britain', id: 'britain'}
              ]}
              placeholder="Please select a country"
            />
          )}
        </FormItem>

        <FormItem
          wrapperCol={{ span: 12, offset: 6 }}
        >
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Submit</Button>
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedDemo = Form.create()(Demo);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedDemo />, mountNode);
```

clone https://github.com/megawac/antd-form-issue and `npm start` to see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5700

> Form need controls's ref, but a functional component don't have ref.

The solution was to use a class based wrapper component in place of the functional based one.

Comment: This helped me. Thank you!!

Comment: I think this was a valid solution pre version 4 of ant-design. Now Makatun's response is probably the way to go (worked for me at least).

Answer (score 2):

How to wrap antd component? Spread love and props!!!

```
import { Select as AntSelect} from 'antd'; 

const Select = (props) => {
    return (<AntSelect {...props} >{props.children}</AntSelect>)
}
```

Comment: You'll probably have issues if using Typescript. If that's the case, import the SelectProps from Ant, and pass Ant's SelectProps instead of just "Props". Then you can basically do the same thing and spread. Will also get autocomplete and IDE support.